# ¿Como activar un href="#id" desde otra pagina .html?

Tags: javascript, html5

Como puedo hacer que al dar clic en un  este active una ruta que debe de llevarme hasta un identificador y dicho identificador debe de realizar una acción secundaria como modal, todo funciona bien desde la misma pagina, ya que la referencia desde ahí mismo, pero en el ejercicio practico debe de funcionar desde otra pagina .html diferente.

Código de linkeo:

```
    <li><a id="demo01" onclick="window.location.href = '#animatedModal';">DEMO01</a></li>
```

Codigo del div al que debe llegar

```
!--DEMO01-->
        <div id="animatedModal">
            <!--THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID -->
            <div  id="btn-close-modal" class="close-animatedModal"> 
                CLOSE MODAL
            </div>

            <div class="modal-content">
                <!--Your modal content goes here-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿ Por qué usar el evento `onclick` y no directamente en el atributo `href` con la página _(sea la misma o diferente )_ incluyendo el `hash` ?

Answer (score 1):

Si por ejemplo ambos ficheros están en la misma carpeta podrías poner el nombre del fichero antes del identificador. En caso de que estuvieran en carpetas distintas, tendrías que poner la ruta al fichero en cuestión.

Ejemplo:

```
<li><a id="demo01" onclick="window.location.href = 'tuOtraPagina.html#animatedModal';">DEMO01</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Como puedo hacer que al dar clic en un este active una ruta que debe de llevarme hasta un identificador y dicho identificador debe de realizar una acción secundaria *«como modal»*.

No sé la forma en que lo hace bootstrap (el ejemplo que siempre veo de esto), pero ahora mismo me imagino una forma en la que se escucha por cambios en la URL y comprobando la misma al cargar el documento.

**Ejemplo**:

```
<div id="anuncio" class="modal">
  <!-- contenido -->
</div>
```

```
window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
  if (!window.location.hash.length) { return }
  const hash = window.location.hash
  const modal = document.querySelector(hash)

  if (modal && modal.classList.contains('modal')) {
    console.log(modal)
  }
})

window.addEventListener('popstate', (e) => {
  if (!window.location.hash.length) { return }
  const hash = window.location.hash
  const modal = document.querySelector(hash)

  if (modal && modal.classList.contains('modal')) {
    console.log(modal)
  }
})
```

En este caso se intenta obtener el hash de la URL. Si lo encuentra, obtiene el elemento con dicho id y posteriormente verifica que tenga la clase `modal`. Esto último es subjetivo, en lugar de una clase puedes usar cualquier otra cosa; el punto es saber si es una modal para proceder a mostrarla.